# Magento - Fatal error(s) after installing module

Tags: magento, module, fatal-error

Just installed Product Accessories on Magento ver. 1.8.0.0

And my whole website went on fatal errors.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object
Fatal error: Call to a member function setStoreId() on a non-object
Fatal error: Class 'Anais_Accessories_Model_Product'
```

What do I need to do to get the module running smooth? I can't find an other module that does the same like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model file name should be like this-->> AnaisAccessories.php. Rename all the classes in the Model folder start with the Uppercase and rest should be lowercase as AnaisAccessories. As you can see you've error in class 'Anais_Accessories_Model_Product'.

- Make sure file ../Model/AnaisAccessories.php should contain below code. Make appropriate change according to your Module.

  ```
  class Anais_Accessories_Model_Accessories extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
  {
  public function _construct()
  {
     parent::_construct();
     $this->_init('accessories/accessories');
  }
  }
  ```